# How to fix 'iOS crash Crashed: WebThread EXC_BREAKPOINT 0x00000001efac65c0'

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an iPad app. Use fabric to collect crashes. Recently there're some crash like webthread EXC_BREAKPOINT. There's no my code on tracing stack. So i don't know why the crash happened.

I've tried many times to reproduce the crash. but it didn't happen.

```
0 Crashed: WebThread EXC_BREAKPOINT 0x00000001efac65c0
0   WebCore bmalloc::IsoAllocator<bmalloc::IsoConfig<1216u> >::allocateSlow(bool) + 252
1 WebCore   bmalloc::IsoAllocator<bmalloc::IsoConfig<1216u> >::allocateSlow(bool) + 72
2   WebCore WebCore::FrameView::create(WebCore::Frame&) + 148
3   WebKitLegacy WebFrameLoaderClient::transitionToCommittedForNewPage() + 652
4   WebCore WebCore::FrameLoader::transitionToCommitted(WebCore::CachedPage*) + 660
5   WebCore WebCore::FrameLoader::commitProvisionalLoad() + 364
6   WebCore WebCore::DocumentLoader::finishedLoading() + 592
7   WebCore WebCore::DocumentLoader::maybeLoadEmpty() + 744
8   WebCore WebCore::DocumentLoader::startLoadingMainResource() + 492
9   WebCore WebCore::FrameLoader::init() + 728
10  WebKitLegacy    +[WebFrame(WebInternal) _createFrameWithPage:frameName:frameView:ownerElement:] + 376
11  WebKitLegacy    WebFrameLoaderClient::createFrame(WTF::URL const&, WTF::String const&, WebCore::HTMLFrameOwnerElement&, WTF::String const&) + 124
12  WebCore WebCore::SubframeLoader::loadSubframe(WebCore::HTMLFrameOwnerElement&, WTF::URL const&, WTF::String const&, WTF::String const&) + 228
13  WebCore 
WebCore::SubframeLoader::loadOrRedirectSubframe(WebCore::HTMLFrameOwnerElement&, WTF::URL const&, WTF::AtomicString const&, WebCore::LockHistory, WebCore::LockBackForwardList) + 324
14  WebCore 
WebCore::SubframeLoader::requestFrame(WebCore::HTMLFrameOwnerElement&, WTF::String const&, WTF::AtomicString const&, WebCore::LockHistory, WebCore::LockBackForwardList) + 676
15  WebCore 
WebCore::HTMLFrameElementBase::openURL(WebCore::LockHistory, WebCore::LockBackForwardList) + 632
16  WebCore 
WebCore::ContainerNode::appendChildWithoutPreInsertionValidityCheck(WebCore::Node&) + 808
17  WebCore 
WebCore::ContainerNode::appendChild(WebCore::Node&) + 80
18  WebCore 
WebCore::jsNodePrototypeFunctionAppendChild(JSC::ExecState*) + 240
19  JavaScriptCore  llint_entry + 89612
20  JavaScriptCore  llint_entry + 82980
21  JavaScriptCore  llint_entry + 82980
22  JavaScriptCore  llint_entry + 82980
23  JavaScriptCore  llint_entry + 82980
24  JavaScriptCore  llint_entry + 82980
25  JavaScriptCore  llint_entry + 82980
26  JavaScriptCore  vmEntryToJavaScript + 268
27  JavaScriptCore  JSC::Interpreter::executeProgram(JSC::SourceCode const&, JSC::ExecState*, JSC::JSObject*) + 9388
28  JavaScriptCore  JSC::evaluate(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::SourceCode const&, JSC::JSValue, WTF::NakedPtr<JSC::Exception>&) + 324
29  WebCore WebCore::JSExecState::profiledEvaluate(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::ProfilingReason, JSC::SourceCode const&, JSC::JSValue, WTF::NakedPtr<JSC::Exception>&) + 108
30  WebCore WebCore::ScriptController::evaluateInWorld(WebCore::ScriptSourceCode const&, WebCore::DOMWrapperWorld&, WebCore::ExceptionDetails*) + 232
31  WebCore 
WebCore::ScriptElement::executeClassicScript(WebCore::ScriptSourceCode const&) + 640
32  WebCore 
WebCore::LoadableClassicScript::execute(WebCore::ScriptElement&) + 140
33  WebCore 
WebCore::ScriptElement::executeScriptAndDispatchEvent(WebCore::LoadableScript&) + 224
34  WebCore WebCore::ScriptRunner::timerFired() + 508
35  WebCore WebCore::ThreadTimers::sharedTimerFiredInternal() + 216
36  WebCore WebCore::timerFired(__CFRunLoopTimer*, void*) + 28
37  CoreFoundation __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 28
38  CoreFoundation  __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 864
39  CoreFoundation  __CFRunLoopDoTimers + 248
40  CoreFoundation  __CFRunLoopRun + 1844
41  CoreFoundation  CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
42  WebCore RunWebThread(void*) + 600
43  libsystem_pthread.dylib _pthread_body + 128
44  libsystem_pthread.dylib _pthread_start + 44
45 libsystem_pthread.dylib  thread_start + 4
```

Is there anyone face the same problem and how do you fix it?

Comment: Can you also include your application flow? looks like you've WebView on screen A and you're moving from A to B. later because of some calls coming from web view your app is crashing (where you webView instance is deallocated).

Comment: @Buntylm The root viewcontroller is a splitviewcontroller. There is viewcontroller A on left, viewcontroller B on right. There's a button on viewcontroller A, when tap the button, will present a viewcontroller which contains a webview. If dismiss the webview controller, it wont be deallocated, because the view controller A retain the webview. There're other buttons when be tapped will change root viewcontroller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this crash is caused by UIWebview's bad memery management. After I replace UIWebview by WKWebview. The crash never happened again.